# Grouping of lines in order to do a final sum to receive a single number

Tags: sql, oracle

There are duplicate Cheque Numbers in my DB that is doubling up my covers, so I need to group those together first then add the covers to get a single figure:

```
  select COVERS into MaxLCov
  from   FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS
  where  TRX_CODE in ('2012', '3002')
  and    to_char(TRX_DATE, 'DD/MM/YY') = :P_DATE
  group by CHEQUE_NUMBER, COVERS;

  select SUM(MaxLCov) into MaxLCover
  from   FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS;

  return MaxLCover;

EXCEPTION
  when NO_DATA_FOUND then return '0';
```

When I run Alex's solution, I receive a sum of 11 covers based on the below data:

```
COVERS  CHEQUE_NUMBER 
1       1041620170404100000 
2       1041720170404120000
1       1041820170404130000 
1       1041820170404130000 
1       1041920170404130000
1       1041920170404130000 
1       1042020170404120000 
1       1042020170404120000
2       1042120170404160000
```

However there are 3 duplicate cheques which each increase my COVERS by 1, which means I get 11 instead of 8 covers.

Got it working with:

```
  MaxLCov    number;
  MaxLCovs   number;
  MaxLCoves  number;
  MaxLCovers number;

begin
  select NVL(sum(COVERS),0) into MaxLCov
  from   FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS
  where  TRX_CODE in ('2012', '3002')
  and    :P_DATE_FROM = TRX_DATE
  and    CHEQUE_NUMBER in
         ( select CHEQUE_NUMBER
           from   FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS
           where  TRX_CODE in ('2012', '3002')
           and    :P_DATE_FROM = TRX_DATE
           GROUP BY CHEQUE_NUMBER HAVING COUNT(CHEQUE_NUMBER) = 1 );

  select NVL(sum(COVERS),0) into MaxLCovs
  from   FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS
  where  TRX_CODE in ('2012', '3002')
  and    :P_DATE_FROM = TRX_DATE
  and    CHEQUE_NUMBER in
         ( select CHEQUE_NUMBER
           from   FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS
           where  TRX_CODE in ('2012', '3002')
           and    :P_DATE_FROM = TRX_DATE
           GROUP BY CHEQUE_NUMBER HAVING COUNT(CHEQUE_NUMBER)=2);

  MaxLCoves  := MaxLCovs/2;
  MaxLCovers := MaxLCov+MaxLCoves;

  return MaxLCovers;

end;
```

Comment: There are duplicate Cheque Numbers in the table hence why i am grouping them first then summing my covers

Comment: Where are you seeing these multiple numbers? Show the whole function and the relevant data in the table, how you're calling the function, and the output you get. I would think your first query would get an exception from trying to get multiple values into a scalar variable. If you don't then you're effectively then multiplying the single value you do get by the number of rows in your table, aren't you? Why are you trying to do this in two steps?

Comment: Hi Alex, I am running this in Oracle Report Builder. When I run the report I get an exception error staying multiple lines. I am running it in seperate queries because I need to first group the covers on the duplicate cheque number so they don't double up then once they are grouped I want to add them together and get the single response. My DB table adds 2 lines, 1 per TRX code and pulls the same covers over two lines so if I need to know how many covers were on one cheque number I have to group the lines.

Comment: It would be much easier to understand if you added sample data and current/expected results, and if you are getting an exception, exactly what that is. (Maybe you're getting "ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"?) I don't think you do need to group, and only need one query not two, but let's see. Also, not directly relevant, but what data type is `p_date` - looks like you're passing a string not a date?

Comment: Thanks Alex that's the exact error I am receiving! I will provide some data in a few hours when I'm back infront of my PC. The P_Date is a parameter and I have to force it to DD/MM/YY as my front end Date is set to that format whilst my DB pulls DD-MON-YY

Comment: What should happen if you have the same cheque number multiple times but with different cover values? (Maybe you should be preventing duplicates in the first place?)

Comment: The same cheque will have Max 2 lines so my script is very specific to my DB (There will only be 2 transaction codes I will be looking for at a time which results in a maximum of 2 lines) I tried your solutions and they work spot on - Thank you very much!

Comment: Removed some blank lines and straightened up alignment to improve readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to use a single aggregate query:

```
  select nvl(sum(COVERS), 0) into MaxLCover
  from FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS
  where TRX_CODE in ('2012', '3002')
  and TRX_DATE = to_date(:P_DATE, 'DD/MM/RR');

  return MaxLCover;
```

You don't need an intermediate stage; you're currently trying to get the cover value for all the matching cheques into a single variable at once, which isn't allowed and is causing the ORA-01422 error; and then you're trying to sum that single value but across all the rows in your table.

You also don't need an exception handler, the `nvl()` combined with the aggregate function means a value will always be found even if no data matches.

And I've switched your date check around, so you're comparing the date column with a date variable, instead of converting both to strings (which involves a lot of conversion on the column side). I've assumed you're passing a string in DD/MM/RR format, based on how you were converting to a string. It would be better to pass a 4-digit year; and even better to pass an actual date rather than a string that has to be converted. I've also assumed that the dates in your column all have the time portion set to midnight - if they have other times then you will need to match against a range rather than a single fixed date (also with midnight).

If you only want to include one cover value for each cheque you need to identify which one. This uses the most recent, or if there are multiples on the same the highest value (which is a bit arbitrary, bu no idea what your real rules would be):

```
  select nvl(sum(max(COVERS) keep (dense_rank last order by TRX_DATE, COVERS)), 0)
  into MaxLCover
  from FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS
  where TRX_CODE in ('2012', '3002')
  and TRX_DATE = to_date(:P_DATE, 'DD/MM/RR')
  group by CHEQUE_NUMBER;
```

With your sample data that gives the sum as 8, so it is OK with the date and cover values being identical too. But if they aren't the same, your real issue is identifying which one to use.

or if you want to include all the covers for each cheque number and use their average you can nest aggregate calls:

```
  select nvl(sum(avg(COVERS)), 0)
  into MaxLCover
  from FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS
  where TRX_CODE in ('2012', '3002')
  and TRX_DATE = to_date(P_DATE, 'DD/MM/RR')
  group by CHEQUE_NUMBER;
```

which also gives 8 with your data.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have tried your solution above (Thank you for the NVL - I've removed my exception) however it is not seeing the duplicate cheque number and therefore is giving me duplicated Covers. I will post my return now without the SUM and then the SUM response

Comment: COVERS CHEQUE_NUMBER                                                                
1 1041620170404100000
2 1041720170404120000
1 1041820170404130000
1 1041820170404130000
1 1041920170404130000
1 1041920170404130000
1 1042020170404120000
1 1042020170404120000
2 1042120170404160000

Comment: Please edit the questioon  to show additional data etx., it isn't readable in comments. Include the original data in your table as well as the current and expected output please.

Comment: Click on EDIT to see it listed properly, now there are 3 duplicated Cheque numbers which each duplicate my covers by 1, so when i SUM using your solution i receive 11 COVERS meanwhile it should be 8 COVERS

Comment: Don't edit a solution into your question, post it as an answer. I've added a way to ignore duplicates more simply by only counting one of them (identifying which has to be done though). You're essentially averaging all of the values, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
MaxLCov number;
MaxLCovs number;
MaxLCoves Number;
MaxLCovers Number;
begin
  select NVL(sum(COVERS),0) into MaxLCov
  from FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS
  where TRX_CODE in ('2012', '3002')
  and :P_DATE_FROM = TRX_DATE
  and CHEQUE_NUMBER in
  (Select CHEQUE_NUMBER
  from FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS
  where TRX_CODE in ('2012', '3002')
  and :P_DATE_FROM = TRX_DATE

  GROUP BY CHEQUE_NUMBER HAVING COUNT(Cheque_Number)=1);

   select NVL(sum(COVERS),0) into MaxLCovs
  from FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS
  where TRX_CODE in ('2012', '3002')
  and :P_DATE_FROM = TRX_DATE
  and CHEQUE_NUMBER in
  (Select CHEQUE_NUMBER
  from FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS
  where TRX_CODE in ('2012', '3002')
  and :P_DATE_FROM = TRX_DATE

  GROUP BY CHEQUE_NUMBER HAVING COUNT(Cheque_Number)=2);

  MaxLCoves :=MaxLCovs/2;


   MaxLCovers := MaxLCov+MaxLCoves;

   return MaxLCovers;


end;
```

Due to duplicate checks being a maximum of 2 lines the above works